# Is this a finer-grained form of Russian Doll caching in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So if I do Russian doll caching this way (Way 1):

```
cache(["todo_list", @todos.map(&:id), @todos.maximum(:updated_at)])
```

versus this way (Way 2):

```
cache(["todo_list", @todos])
```

Is there any difference?